# Anyone has any idea how to perform the Fourier transform in this case?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Anyone has any idea how to perform the Fourier transform in this case? I'm pretty new to the subject....

$$ f(t) = t^2 e^{-5|t|}$$

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992 and never include equations by inserting an image.

Comment: I edited your question to convert the image into an equation. Please review and verify that I did not err.

Answer (score 3):

$$
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^2 e^{-5|t|}e^{-ixt}dt = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5|t|}e^{-ixt}dt \\
   = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{5t}e^{-ixt}dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-5t}e^{-ixt}dt\right] \\
   = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac{1}{5-ix}+\frac{1}{5+ix}\right] \\
   = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac{10}{25+x^2}\right]
$$

Comment: +1 for the hidden double disintegration by parts